# Operating system wasn't found

Tags: boot, partitioning

How to resolve this error?

```
An operating system wasn't found .Try disconnecting contain an operating system
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

How to fix this problem after partitioning HDD?

Comment: more details please. how the error happens, what operating system you installed, what you have done, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by the overwriting or deletion of the MBR/GRUB, which tells the computer where the OS' are and where to boot them from.

If you have been partitioning you probably overwrote the GRUB files, something that is commonly done. I did it myself once.

The fix depends on if you have an OS installed yet.

If you do:

- Boot a LiveCD/USB and run GRUB Boot Repair. If you google it, tons of results will come up, several being tutorials.

You can download an ISO with it included here: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ or download/install it in the Ubuntu LiveCD. If you are using the Ubuntu LiveCD, read on. If you are using the ISO with it included, jump ahead to step 2, explaining the repair process.

**1 How to install boot-repair in the Ubuntu LiveCD**:

> - boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
> - choose "Try Ubuntu"
> - connect internet
> - open a new Terminal, then type:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
>   update`
>
> - Press Enter.
> - Then type:
>
> `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
>
> - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**2. How To Run Boot-repair**:

Once you have it, to fix the boot record, run it like this:

> **Recommended repair**
>
> ```
> launch Boot-Repair from either :
>     the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
>
>     or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
>     or by typing `boot-repair` in a terminal 
>
> Then click the <kbd>Recommended</kbd> repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a
> ```
>
> paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
>       If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

---

If there is no OS installed, just install a new Ubuntu installation! This will write new GRUB files and it should get rid of this error!